# Google "Start Page" Service is missing from Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace

I'm using Google Apps Standard Edition on two different domains. On one of them when I press **Add more services**, I see the **Start Page** service which will:

> Let [domain] users access services from a
>   central place. Preview inboxes and
>   calendar events, access essential
>   content, and search the web`.

... but on the other I don't see this Google Service listed. I'm trying to enable it on the one where it doesn't show up.

Notes:

- The **Start Page** is listed directly underneath **Google Services**, not under **Other services**. It's not listed as **New!** or **Labs**.
- I made sure that the important **Domain Settings** of both sites are exactly the same: Automatically add new services when the become available (enabled), Enable pre-release features (enabled), and Control panel (Next generation).
- I noticed another difference between the two domain's control panels: on the one with **Start Page**, it's missing the **Domain Names** tab under **Domain Settings**. If I go to the other site's **Domain Settings** page, I see only one domain listed, since I haven't used this feature.
- I am logged in as an administrator to both control panels (obviously).
- The one that has the **Start Page** option, I created about a week ago. The one without the option, I created about a year ago.
- With the exception of this one service, they both show the exact same services that can be added or removed.
- Searching the Google Apps Marketplace for `Start Page` doesn't return any relevant results.

**Update:** I just logged in today and now I do see the service listed.

Comment: I experienced a similar thing where Google Wave appeared on that screen for one domain's account but refused to appear on another domain's account. It fixed itself after a few weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be available, but has been discontinued:

> Note: The previous Start Page service
>   was a syndicated version of iGoogle;
>   it allows you to set up a dynamic
>   homepage (one start page layout per
>   domain) for your users that brings
>   together your content, Google
>   services, and the best of the web.
>   Starting on 3 December 2008, the Start
>   Page is no longer included for new
>   organizations that sign up for Google
>   Apps.

(From: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46798)

However, you can now make your own via Google Sites:

> As a Google Apps administrator, you
>   can create a Start Page for your
>   users, using the Google Sites Start
>   Page template. This page is your
>   users' homepage, on which they can
>   access their Google services and other
>   content -- such as interactive gadgets
>   and RSS feeds -- when they log in to
>   their Google Apps accounts.their Google Apps accounts.

(From the tutorial: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=179916

Comment: That's weird since the one I created earlier (possibly before DEC 2008) doesn't have the Start Page, while the one I created a week ago does.

Comment: How odd. Did you manage to create one via Sites for the older one OK?

Comment: I tried following the tutorial, unfortunately, the Start Page template doesn't exist for me. In [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/sites/thread?tid=1ed30975d1331427&hl=en), someone says that it is only a Google Apps Premier Edition feature.

Comment: **Update:** I just logged in today and now I do see the service listed.